# Using kepresses and if statements to enable and disable elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am using electron to build an app that has a fullscreen feature (of course). I am trying to use the F11 key (keyCode = "85") to enable a message on my Html page that tells the user to press F11 to exit fullscreen. I am using `var i = 0` to set the `status` of the fullscreen app, where `i = 0;` is not fullscreen and where `i = 1;` is fullscreen. This feature is partially working except for when I try to disable it by pressing <kbd>F11</kbd>. When pressed, the element does not set its display to `none`.

What am I doing *wrong*? Thanks!

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);

function checkKeyPressed(e) {
  var i = 0;

  if (i == "0") {
    if (e.keyCode = "85") {
      document.getElementById('exitfullscreenmessage').style.display = "block";
      i = 1;
    }
  } else if (i == "1") {
    if (e.keyCode = "85") {
      document.getElementById('exitfullscreenmessage').style.display = "none";
      i = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `i` as a boolean - it is used EVERYWHERE as the index in a loop. You need to move your boolean declaration outside the function: `var isPressed=false; function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    if (e.keyCode = "85") {
      document.getElementById('exitfullscreenmessage').style.display = isPressed?"none":"block"; isPressed = !isPressed;}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're re-initializing `i` to `0` every time you enter the function. You need to move the variable out of the function.

You should also use boolean values to implement alternating values, not `1/0`. And don't put quotes around numbers.

You also had a typo, you were using `=` instead of `==` when testing `e.keyCode`.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);
var fullscreenmessage = false;

function checkKeyPressed(e) {
  //the correct keycode for F11 is 122
  if (e.keyCode == 122) {
    document.getElementById('exitfullscreenmessage').style.display = fullscreenmessage ? "none" : "block";
    fullscreenmessage = !fullscreenmessage;
  }
}
```

```css
#exitfullscreenmessage {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="exitfullscreenmessage">Exit full screen</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Good idea, although if you declare the loop counter as a local variable, as you always should, they won't interfere.

Comment: a problem now is that no matter what key you press it enables it then you press any key and it disables it. I need it to just be the f11 key only @Barmar

Comment: `=` should be `==` in the `if` condition.

Comment: Thank you! As it turns out, the key codes were wrong. Google said it was 85 for F11, but in fact it is 122 @Barmar

Comment: I couldn't actually test F11, since that's a standard Mac OS shortcut.